# eclipse option (luna) to turn quick fix back on

Tags: eclipse

Not sure what i typed by accident, some key sequence, and a popup appeared/disappeared in luna eclipse editor.  After that the quick fix stop popping up, which is kinda handy for imports and new classes. It Quick fix continues to work in other projects in same workspace, and in other work spaces. Been through the options, can't find one. Replaced luna, still no go. Looked throug project files, still don't see it.
Any ideas, other than create a new project?